# Foreach on hash variables in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, foreach

I am new to Perl scripting and have a doubt on `foreach` on hash variables. I want to print all values of my hash. Here's a program:

```
%colors = (a => 1, b=>2, c=>3, d=>4, e=>5);
foreach $colors(keys %colors)
{
    print "$colors{%colors} \n";
}
```

The output is:

```
5
3
1
2
4
```

Why are the values sorted randomly? Or what's the logic behind this randomness?? Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Please do not insert `<BR>` all over your posts. Use the markdown editing instead.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Will do that next time when I post. Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that your confusion lies in not knowing exactly what a Hash *is*. Most languages have something analogous to a key-value store, in Ruby and Perl they are called Hashes, in Java Maps, in Python dictionaries, etc...

They are all essentially the same thing, you insert a value with a unique key into some underlying data structure to gain direct access to it at the cost of memory.

*So what actually happens when you add a key and a value to a hash?*

Hashes are built around the idea of *[hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)* which take some value as input computes a unique output (ideally every input has their own unique output). If two inputs both map to the same output, this is called a *collision*.

Now we are at the point where we need to talk about how the Hash is implemented, the two classic examples are with a single array or an array of linked-lists. I will show the array example below.

*Array*

In the simple array case the data structure underlying the Hash is just an array of some size. The hashing function is used to compute an index into that array. If we assume a simple hashing algorithm

```
h(x) = length(x) % ARRAY_SIZE
```

here `x` is a string and `ARRAY_SIZE` is the size of our underlying array, this statement will make sure that all values `x` will fall in the range `0..ARRAY_SIZE - 1`

To look at a visual example consider an array of size 5:

```
   0     1     2     3     4
 ------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |      |
 ------------------------------
```

and assume we are trying to store the value `5` using key `abcd`, according to our hashing algorithm

```
h('abcd') = length('abcd') % ARRAY_SIZE
          =      4         %      5
          =      4
```

So the value `5` will be stored at index `4`:

```
   0     1     2     3     4
 ------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |   5  |
 ------------------------------
```

now what would happen if we were to try to store the value `3` using the key `dcba`, the two keys are different right? They should map to different places.

```
h('dcba') = length('dcba') % ARRAY_SIZE
          =      4         %      5
          =      4
```

Oops! This key also maps to index `4` so what are we going to do now? Well we can't just throw away the key-value pair because the programmer obviously needs/wants this pairing in their Hash so we need to decide what to do in the event of a collision. There are many algorithms that do this, but the simplest one is to look for the next open slot in the array and store `3` their. So now our array looks like:

```
   0     1     2     3     4
 ------------------------------
|   3  |     |     |     |  5  |
 ------------------------------
```

This was not an extremely in-depth explanation, but hopefully it will give some insight into why retrieving values from Hashes seems *random*, its because the underlying data structure constantly changes, if you were to ask for the keys from your Hash right now you would probably get back `(3, 5)`, even though you inserted `5` first, only because `3` occurs first in the array.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: IIRC Perl uses key chaining/closed addressing; each hash entry contains a pointer to the next HE. Otherwise, great writeup.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about the actual Perl implementation details, but that scheme seems common.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [perldata - Perl data types](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> Hashes are unordered collections of scalar values indexed by their associated string key.

You can [`sort`](http://p3rl.org/sort) the keys, or, if you want to preserve the order given in the initialization, use [Tie::Hash::Indexed](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aIndexed) or [Tie::IxHash](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aIxHash).

Comment: Doesn't explain why there is randomness.

Answer (score 3):

The description of `keys` in the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) has the following snippet:

> > Hash entries are returned in an apparently random order. The actual random order is specific to a given hash; the exact same series of operations on two hashes may result in a different order for each hash. Any insertion into the hash may change the order, as will any deletion, with the exception that the most recent key returned by each or keys may be deleted without changing the order. So long as a given hash is unmodified you may rely on keys, values and each to repeatedly return the same order as each other. See [Algorithmic Complexity Attacks in perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks) for details on why hash order is randomized. Aside from the guarantees provided here the exact details of Perl's hash algorithm and the hash traversal order are subject to change in any release of Perl.

[Perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks) says the following about Hash Algorithms:

> - Hash Algorithm - Hash algorithms like the one used in Perl are well known to be vulnerable to collision attacks on their hash function. Such attacks involve constructing a set of keys which collide into the same bucket producing inefficient behavior. Such attacks often depend on discovering the seed of the hash function used to map the keys to buckets. That seed is then used to brute-force a key set which can be used to mount a denial of service attack. In Perl 5.8.1 changes were introduced to harden Perl to such attacks, and then later in Perl 5.18.0 these features were enhanced and additional protections added.
>     At the time of this writing, Perl 5.18.0 is considered to be well-hardened against algorithmic complexity attacks on its hash implementation. This is largely owed to the following measures mitigate attacks:
>
>   - **Hash Seed Randomization**
>       In order to make it impossible to know what seed to generate an attack key set for, this seed is randomly initialized at process start. This may be overridden by using the PERL_HASH_SEED environment variable, see PERL_HASH_SEED in perlrun. This environment variable controls how items are actually stored, not how they are presented via **keys**, **values** and **each**.
>   - **Hash Traversal Randomization**
>       Independent of which seed is used in the hash function, **keys**, **values**, and **each** return items in a per-hash randomized order. Modifying a hash by insertion will change the iteration order of that hash. This behavior can be overridden by using hash_traversal_mask() from Hash::Util or by using the PERL_PERTURB_KEYS environment variable, see PERL_PERTURB_KEYS in perlrun. Note that this feature controls the "visible" order of the keys, and not the actual order they are stored in.
>   - **Bucket Order Perturbance**
>       When items collide into a given hash bucket the order they are stored in the chain is no longer predictable in Perl 5.18. This has the intention to make it harder to observe a collisions. This behavior can be overridden by using the PERL_PERTURB_KEYS environment variable, see PERL_PERTURB_KEYS in perlrun.
>   - **New Default Hash Function**
>       The default hash function has been modified with the intention of making it harder to infer the hash seed.
>   - **Alternative Hash Functions**
>       The source code includes multiple hash algorithms to choose from. While we believe that the default perl hash is robust to attack, we have included the hash function Siphash as a fall-back option. At the time of release of Perl 5.18.0 Siphash is believed to be of cryptographic strength. This is not the default as it is much slower than the default hash.
>
> Without compiling a special Perl, there is no way to get the exact same behavior of any versions prior to Perl 5.18.0. The closest one can get is by setting PERL_PERTURB_KEYS to 0 and setting the PERL_HASH_SEED to a known value. We do not advise those settings for production use due to the above security considerations.
>
> Perl has never guaranteed any ordering of the hash keys, and the ordering has already changed several times during the lifetime of Perl 5. Also, the ordering of hash keys has always been, and continues to be, affected by the insertion order and the history of changes made to the hash over its lifetime.
>
> Also note that while the order of the hash elements might be randomized, this "pseudo-ordering" should **not** be used for applications like shuffling a list randomly (use List::Util::shuffle() for that, see List::Util, a standard core module since Perl 5.8.0; or the CPAN module Algorithm::Numerical::Shuffle ), or for generating permutations (use e.g. the CPAN modules Algorithm::Permute or Algorithm::FastPermute ), or for any cryptographic applications.

Comment: It has nothing to do with that. Even if the defenses were removed, the elements wouldn't be returned in theorder they were inserted.

Comment: @ikegami Adding the notes from perlsec as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sort to print out the results in an alphabetically (as your keys are alphanumerics) sorted manner like this:

```
%colors = ("a" => 1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
foreach (sort keys %colors) {
    print $colors{$_} . "\n";
}
```

Alternatively if you prefer to sort by the values:

```
%colors = ("a" => 1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
foreach (sort { $colors{$a} <=> $colors{$b} } keys %colors) {
    print $colors{$_} . "\n";
}
```